# By what logic did a font search question get migrated to Webmasters?

Tags: discussion, migration

See [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23468/looking-for-a-font-free-or-paid-version). Can someone get whatever mod approved that in here to explain?
I've ocassionaly had the unprovable thought that some at SO treat this site as a dump for things they don't want to deal with, but this one's just silly.

Comment: FYI, that question has been migrated to GD straight from StackOverflow so I have removed it from our site. That was arranged behind the scenes with the GD and SO mods.

Answer (score 3):

The moderators over at SO are actually very courteous when migrating questions over to us. When they have a questionable migration they ask the Webmaster mods in the Moderator chatroom if we want it or if it should just be closed at SO.

On the other hand, if five SO members with 3,000 rep decide a question is coming here whether it should or not, well, it's coming here whether it should or not. So the real question is how do we deal with that?

Comment: You're right; I missed that there wasn't actually a mod involved. As far as what to do, my own instinct would be to re-migrate the question correctly as soon as possible, at least for things that are this completely wrong(there've been some that while not idea can at least be handled as roughly enough on-topic). What you did in this case won't scale. On the other hand, my understanding is that multiple migrations are discouraged, so maybe there needs to be talk of exceptions to that.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe 3000 rep is now too low for a user on SO to be able to vote questions to other sites?  We receive a small number of migrations from SO that are completely ridiculous and John Conde is right, they are almost exclusively from 5 users voting to close it and migrate it here.

By my estimates, there are over 7,500 users on SO currently that have over the 3,000 rep that it takes to close and migrate a question.

Also, how does migration from 5 votes work?  Does it go to the site that has the most votes as to where it goes?  What happens if the vote is split?

Comment: Granting the ability to influence an auto-migration based on some kind of sliding ratio of user population/rep is a really interesting idea. That said, if I remember correctly, two of the voters here were above 20k and at least one other in the 8-9k range, so there does still seem to be an education factor involved. There's just a hole in the process here that I'm not sure how to address. Having high rep doesn't directly translate into being able to assume that person knows anything at all about the other available sites. Something like the flag weight system seems more applicable.

Comment: `Maybe 3000 rep is now too low for a user on SO to be able to vote questions to other sites?` Well basically you can have 10000 rep on SO and still don't really know what site it should be on. Rep on any stack exchange site doesn't mean you know exactly about the other sites.